# How do I write a regex to match all single characters in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace all single non-whitespace characters from a string with a space.

I have tried this.

```
string = 'This is a test string'
string.gsub(/(\W|\A).(\W|\z)/, ' ')
 => "This is test string"
```

Which works great. But if I have two consecutive single characters, it only finds the first.

```
string = 'This is a x test string'
string.gsub(/(\W|\A).(\W|\z)/, ' ')
 => "This is x test string"
```

I am not sure which regex principle I am missing here that I need to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a character here? Any character or just an ASCII letter? What is the expected output for `This is a x - test string`?

Comment: Try `string.gsub(/\s+.(?=\s|\z)/, '')`

Comment: If you replace all single characters with a space, you will always just get a sequence of spaces with the same length as the original string. An easy way would be `" " * string.length`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it should be any non-whitespace character.

Comment: `(?<=\s)\S(?=\s)` would do the best.

Comment: In your code, you are no replacing a character with a space as you wrote, you are removing it and one of its adjacent characters.

Comment: Maybe `\s+\S(?!\S)|\A\S\s+` is also worth a try.

Comment: Isn't your question wrong? You want to *remove* all single character words with accompanying space, don't you? If you wanted to *replace* `This is a x test string` would end up like `This is_____test string` (where `_` are spaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex principle in use here is `word boundary`.

Try with `\b[A-Za-z]\b` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5hA6/1)

This will work most of the time except if there is some other character than word. Such as `a@` then it will consider `a` as single character because there is a word boundary between `a` and `@` like this `a|@`.

In that case you can also go with `look-around` assertions which will look for `space` on both side of letter. So as to qualify as single character.

**Regex:** `(?<=\s)[A-Za-z](?=\s)`  [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5hA6/2)

---

**Update #1:**

For non-whitespace character use `\S` or `[^\s]` in search pattern.

Regex will be `(?<=\s)[^\s](?=\s)` Or `(?<=\s)\S(?=\s)` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5hA6/3)

---

**Update #2:**

To match at beginning or at end of string, added `^` and `$` into lookaround assertions.

**Regex:** `(?<=^|\s)[^\s](?=\s|$)`  [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ4nR2/2)

*Note:-* Use used `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` if latter doesn't works.

Comment: The latter one is fine. The first should be removed, as it fails on `"a-b-c"` and family.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Yea, I was adding reason for that exception.

Comment: It needs to match any non-whitespace char (I'll edit the question to reflect this)

Comment: based on this I think this works: (?<=\s)[^\s](?=\s) - https://regex101.com/r/cY9wI7/1 . Can you see any issues with that?

Comment: @DanSingerman: In that case you need to use `\S` which is short for `[^\s]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`. I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Really close. Just doesn't match a trailing single char: https://regex101.com/r/wJ4nR2/1

Comment: @DanSingerman: Should had thought of it. [Fixed](https://regex101.com/r/wJ4nR2/2). Regex would be `(?<=^|\s)[^\s](?=\s|$)`

Comment: @noob here obviously should be used `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I will add a note.

Comment: `^` and `$` match *not*  “beginning or at end of *string*” but rather “beginning or at end of *line*” in multiline strings. And please change `\Z` to `\z`.

Answer (score 1):

And here is a non-regexp version:

```
string = 'This is x a test string'

single_character = -> x { x.size == 1 } 

p string.split(' ').reject(&single_character).join(' ') #=> "This is test string"
```

Comment: Ha, I went with something like this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundary `\b` like this:

```
string = 'This­ is a x y z test strin­g'
string.gsu­b(/\b\w\b/­, ' ').gs­ub(/\s{2,}­/, ' ')
=> "This is test string"
```

Others characters can be used with char classes like this:  `[\w\-]` or a not space char like this: `(?<=\s)\S(?=\s)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookahead (or lookbehind). Then the space before (or after with lookbehind) wont be included in the match, and you replace with the empty string.

```
string = 'This is a x test string'
string.gsub(/(?<=\W|\A).(\W|\z)/, '')
=> "This is test string"
```

I'd restrict the character matched in between to a `\w`, and maybe move to unicode aware character classes.

Comment: Match specifically on whitespace, not `\W`, if `a-b-c` should be treated as one word. `/(?<=\s|\A)\w(\s|\z)/`

Comment: There's an edge-case with beginning or end of string. If you picked look-ahead, this would leave a space at the end of `"Single character at the end: a"`. I'd just strip it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to **remove** single instances of *non-whitespace*. Try replacing

```
\s\S(?!\S)|(?<!\S)\S\s
```

with nothing - `""`.

[Se an example here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eJ1hU5/2).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't think that's what you intended, but you made me realize a mistake in my regex (fixed). I really don't know *what* you mean by your comment, because your pattern simply doesn't work. Why I've got the alternatives, if that is what you got hung up on, is to handle single *letters* at the beginning **and** the end. Maybe that's what you get at.

Comment: I mean that `(?!\S)\S` is an always failing subpattern (a non whitespace character, and a test that checks if there isn't a non whitespace character for the same position). The corrected pattern should work, but note that `(?<!\S)\S\s` will only succeed at the start of the string since all other single non-whitespace characters (preceded by a whitespace) are matched by the first branch `\s\S(?!\S)`. In this case writing : `\s\S(?!\S)|^\S\s` produces the same result. Note too that a string with a single non-whitespace character doesn't match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Gotcha. God thing that my considerations (start and end of string) since got picked up on by noob and OP got a working answer then :)