# Regular expression - nothing to left of string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that finds **T1** in a string. I don't want it to match however if there is any text in front of it (spaces are ok), so:

```
this is T1 - match

this isT1 - not a match

T1 - match
```

`^(?=.*[T])(?=.*[0-4])` this is what i have currently that can match T1 up to T4.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Word boundary is not enough. It will match `@T1` too.

Comment: @noob Good point - deleted my answer :-)

Comment: What is the language flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for start or string or space before `T1` will do.

**Regex:** `(?<=^|\s)T\d+`

**Explanation:** This looks-behind if  there is any `space` before `T1` or it is at beginning of string. If yes then `T1`, `T2` or even `T987` will match.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT8hJ1/2)**

---

### **Additionally**

If you want to impose this restriction on both sides use following regex.

**Regex:** `(?<=^|\s)T\d+(?=\s|$)`

**Explanation:** This will lookahead as well as look-behind. Both on left and right side.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT8hJ1/3)**

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Done ! Also check [this answer for word boundary conflicts.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617788/how-do-i-write-a-regex-to-match-all-single-characters-in-a-string/36617842#36617842)

Comment: And if the language flavor is JS?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: [NSRegularExpressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860703/regex-for-text-within-braces) support lookarounds, so we can use this.

Comment: The problem is, there are two tags, one for Qt and another one for Objective-C. Both are mostly used because there is "regular expression" inside these tags. However, it seems OP really might be coding for iOS (I checked OP history).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Should wait for OP's reply to your comment.

Comment: **[QRegularExpression implements Perl-compatible regular expressions.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details)** I hope this means **Yes, it supports lookaround assertions.**

Comment: You misunderstood me: I mean the regex flavor may be any when those 2 tags are used alongside with the regex tag.

Comment: @noob: Wiktor is right, those two tags are used incorrectly more often than not, which is why I deleted them.  Many, um, newcomers aren't confident that [tag:regex] is sufficient because it doesn't contain the whole phrase "regular expression".  If they don't give some other indication that they're using iOS or qt or whatever, you should always question those tags.